# How to integrate codeigniter and javascript for validation?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a some simple `code igniter` `PHP` code that I wish to validate to ensure that only **10** chars max can be typed in the `Text area`. I wish to use `JavaScript` for the validation. How can I integrate the both?

Below shows the `PHP/codeigniter` and rough `javascript` code that I am going to use.

Can I add the javascript as a 3rd parameter in the echo `form_textarea` method as described [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)?

**PHP:**

```
echo form_textarea('age',set_value('age',0));
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField,limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } 
}
</script>
```

So would the following work? :

```
$js = 'onKeyDown="limitText(age,10)"';

echo form_textarea('age',set_value('age',0),$js);
```

Comment: what html code does echo form_textarea('age',set_value('age',0),$js); produce?

Comment: Just something to think about: What if the user has JavaScript disabled? It's handy to use both Server-Side and Client-Side Validation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, pass the value and the onKeyDown in the second argument. You could even include `maxlength` that works with text areas so you don't need to use your JavaScript function.

```
$options = array(
  "value" => 0,
  "onKeyDown" => "limitText(age, 10)",
  "maxlength" => 10 //only include if you want this instead of javascript
);

echo form_textarea('age', $options);
```

Comment: thanks, however where do I put the javascript function within my code, Is it within the php tags?

Comment: No, you'd put it in the view, so in the html between the `<body>` tags. @user9991110000

Comment: can it not be put between the php tags, by using echo, e.g. <?php echo '<script> function()......</script>; ?>

Comment: It can be. @user9991110000

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't do anything other than what maxlength does. Just use maxlength.

Comment: Yes I know, my comment was directed @user9991110000; I should have clarified that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only with HTML:

```
  <textarea maxlength="50">
    Some text
  </textarea>
```

This will work only on HTML5 supported browsers.

using javascript:
html:

```
<textarea onchange="myFunction()"> </textarea>
```

javaScript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").length;
    if (x.length < 3) {
      alert("Some error msg!");
    }

}
</script>
```

To validate using codeIgniter take a at [form validation documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html).